# How to manage very large Solr indexes

Tags: solr, bigdata, solrcloud

I'm trying to plan a SolrCloud implementation, and given current index sizes from testing, my estimated physical index size for 1 billion documents is roughly 20 terabytes. So far, I've been unable to find a cloud host that can support a single volume of this size. I was hoping somebody could provide some guidance with regard to managing an index this large. Is a 20TB index absurd? Is there something I'm missing with regard to SolrCloud architecture? Most of the guidelines I've seen indicate that the entire index, regardless of shard count, should be replicated on every machine to guarantee redundancy, so every node would require a 20TB storage device. If there's anyone out there who can shed some light, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure where you read such guidelines?

It is totally normal to keep only a portion of the index in each shard (each shard having one master and a number of replicas).

You would need to study how to shard your index, using built in routing based on a hash or provide your own.

Edit: so if I understand correctly, you are assuming that every node in the cluster must have either a master or a replica of EVERY shard, correct? If so, the answer is no. In order to provide resilience, you need to have master/replicas of every shard somewhere in the cluster, but you can have a node N that does not contain anything from shard S, as long as S has a master and a replica (at least) in other nodes.

Comment: I don't think I made myself clear. I understand that an index is broken into shards. My point is that each of those shards is made redundant by being available on different machines. If I have a single index, broken into 4 shards, and I have 3 nodes in my cluster, each of the 3 nodes has either a master or replica of the 4 shards. Therefore, each node technically has the entire index available, regardless of number of shards. If neither a master nor replica of a shard is available on a machine, you've lost fail-over, right?

Comment: @LandonC tried to reply to your question in the edit

Comment: I completely understand your edit, and that's what I was asking: how do people handle indexes of this size? I've researched SolrCloud thoroughly, and I know you don't _have_ to have the full index on each node. I was trying to determine what common practices are. If you Google SolrCloud, every diagram you find will indicate the standard setup I mentioned: full replication of all shards on every node. I was trying to get a feel for peoples' real-world architectures outside of the standard.

Comment: I guess what you see is the side effect of choosing a very simple (2/3 node 2/3 shard) example to draw the diagrams for explaining purposes...